# How to know when my app is executing on Google-Chrome-ARC?

Tags: android, google-chrome-arc

I want to have some different behaviors if my app executes on Google-Chrome-ARC.

I currently get the IMEI, which is null on ARC.

```
public boolean isArc(Context context) {
  TelephonyManager tm = ((TelephonyManager)context
           .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));
  String imei = tm.getDeviceId();
  return imei == null;
}
```

But is it reliable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/getstarted_arc#bestpractices):

> If you need to check if your app is running on Chrome OS, look for `chromium` as the `android.os.Build.BRAND` and `android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER`.

I would not rely upon a `null` device ID.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isRunningOnChrome() {
    boolean res = false;
    String brand_code = android.os.Build.BRAND;
    String manufac_code = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;

    if (null != brand_code && brand_code.contains("chromium")) {
        res = true;
    }

    if (null != manufac_code && manufac_code.contains("chromium")) {
        res = true;
    }

    return res;
}
```